# Paneitz-Branson operator and Q-curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde, conformal-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ a n-dimensional Riemannian manifold, $n\neq 4$, and $h=u^{\frac{4}{n-4}}g$. Then the formula that connect the Panitz-Branson opertator $P_g$ and the Q-curvature $Q_{h}$ is

$Q_h=\frac{2}{n-4}u^{-\frac{n+4}{n-4}}P_{g}u$.

Where is a proof of this fact?

Comment: $Q_g$ should appear int the formula like the scalar curvature for the conformal laplacian. I think you will ding what you what in the original paper of Branson, http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.53.5135&rep=rep1&type=pdf, see 1.10 for instance